# Ajax request callback code doesn't work on Intel xdk app preview on android device

Tags: ajax, cordova, intel-xdk

My project was working perfectly, but after I upgraded to Intel XDK 3088 and higher(3240 version), my getJson function success in connecting to url but call back code doesn't function ,

```
     function get(){
   var settings = {
     "async": true,
   "crossDomain": true,
 "url": "http://wemarketemails.com/alhadaf/api/get_posts/?post_type=car",
      "method": "GET",
  }

       $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
         });
```

This code is working on emulator but doesn't work on app preview on android device, console doesn't print any thing. 
when I search about solutions, I try to install whitelist plugin from cordova, and I set
            
that solution make request found the url that I get data with.

Comment: i'm using jquery mobile framework 1.4.5

Answer (score 0):

OK Dears, the problem was solved for me, as the following:
when i upgraded to Intel XDK 3240, i missed to upgrade jquery min version, i was using  version 1.12.0 so i replace it with the version 2.2.3 and include it at the header of index page,now code work on device with Intel xdk app previewer .